# Is it possible to make Windows Form application devloped in vs as plugin in eclips?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, windows

Is it possible to have plugin of the project in eclipse which is build in visual studio as windows application?

Comment: Eclipse plugins must be written in Java using the Eclipse APIs - so No.

Comment: Is there any way around to make it possible... may be by using any third party tools?

Comment: Extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Eclipse is written in Java and runs on the JVM.

Visual studio is for .Net develpment on the CLR (and similar).

If you want to write an Eclipse plugin, Start here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html

Java isn't too hard to learn if you know C#.